# Customised Harvard referencing

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, harvard-style, authoryear

I'm asked to use Harvard in my report but the examiner requires that the in-text citation should appear in the references (bibliography) section. I' using **LyX** but I can't manage to find a way to achieve without manually generating the bibliography.

**In the report:**

some text to be cited (Abras et al., 2004).

**In the references page I have:**

Abras, C., Maloney-Krichmar, D. and Preece, J., 2004. User-centered design. User-centered design, January, pp.445–456.

what the examiner wants is:

**In the report:**

some text to be cited (Abras et al., 2004).

**In the references page:**

(Abras et al., 2004) Abras, C., Maloney-Krichmar, D. and Preece, J., 2004. User-centered design. User-centered design, January, pp.445–456.

Is there a way to achieve this automatically?

Thanks!

===

I updated the question to clarify the issue.

My LyX document bibliography settings
[image: My LyX document bibliography settings]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. "Harvard style" is not a unique designation; while it is (almost universally) used as a synonym for "author-year citation call-outs", it does not restrict how the entries are supposed to be formatted in the bibliography. Does your examiner really want you to suppress all names but the very first one in the formatted bibliographic entries? This would be most unusual, to put it politely. And what's the purpose of placing parentheses around the author/year group in the formatted bibliographic entries? FWIW, I can't perceive any valid purpose...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.